# Animate line in Mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, animation, dictionary, mapbox

I need to animate a curve from one point to another using Mapbox.js.

I looked through the official examples and I saw that simply drawing the line is very easy using Arc.js.

So I thought, is it possible to export points of the curve that is made with Arc.js and use them to animate a line using Mapbox.js?

Or only possible way to animate lines is coming up with formula?

Answer (score 0):

Just like in movies, animation is simply a series of still images: you would take the arc generated by Arc.js, make 'frames' of sub-sections of it, and call `.addData` or `.setGeoJSON()` repeatedly, depending on whether you're using L.geoJson or L.mapbox.featureLayer. You would do this on a `setInterval` or `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` in order to run the calls across time.